# Reg Exp for string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, node.js

i am looking for create a regular exp in JavaScript to look for patterns like `${.............}`. Lets say if have string like

```
{
      "type" : "id",
      "id" : ${idOf('/tar/check/inof/high1')},
      "details" : [
        {
          "name" : "Sanio",
          "sig" : "DA123QW"
        },
        {
          "name" : "Tarer",
          "sig" : "BAWE3QW"
        },
        {
          "name" : "Kadek",
          "sig" : "KSWE2J"
        },
      ]
    },
```

So i am searching for all patterns having ${whateverhere}

i am trying with

```
var pathRegExp = /\$(.*)\}/;
```

But it is not ending at "}" symbol.

Comment: What your expected result?

Comment: i am searching for patterns like  "${idOf('/tar/check/inof/high1')}" and wanted to encode them in double qoutes for JSON conversion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Match pattern

If you want to match `${...}` pattern then you can use this regex:

```
\$\{.*?\}
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/wO2vE7/1)**

[image]

### Match pattern and grab content

On the other hand, if you want to capture the content within `${...}` you can use capturing groups like this:

```
\$\{(.*?)\}
    ^---^--- Capture here
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/wO2vE7/2)**

[image]

The match information would be:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [38-67] `idOf('/tar/check/inof/high1')`
MATCH 2
1.  [199-209]   `anotherOne`
```

If you take a look at the `Code generator` section you can find the **javascript** code for this:

```
var re = /\$\{(.*?)\}/g; 
var str = '{\n      "type" : "id",\n      "id" : ${idOf(\'/tar/check/inof/high1\')},\n      "details" : [\n        {\n          "name" : "Sanio",\n          "sig" : "DA123QW"\n        },\n        {\n          "name" : "${anotherOne}",\n          "sig" : "BAWE3QW"\n        },\n        {\n          "name" : "Kadek",\n          "sig" : "KSWE2J"\n        },\n      ]\n    },';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: There could be multiple entries of "id". But this regular expression is not searching for all them...Any suggestions?

Comment: @gpapps you have to set the `G` (global) flag. I've just edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

It sound's like you need to change it to something like this:

```
var pathRegExp = /\${(.*?)}/g;
```

Check it out here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gS9dX8/1)

I made it become lazy, since Regex is greedy by default and was looking for the last `}` by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex you are looking for:

```
\$\{[^}]*\}
```

This way, it matches with the first ocurrence of '}', because [^}] means "match any character but '}'".

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the opening curly brace `{`

This should work:

```
/\$\{(.*)\}/
```